# Pygame how to record keyboard movement while playing the game

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard

So im trying to make tetris that also records players movement and then plays it back, think of it as a replay function.

I have tried implementing keyboard library ,but the problem with it is that when I try to `record(recorded_events = keyboard.record("esc"))` it the whole game freezes until i press "esc" and when i try to play it back it, it freezes and does nothing.

Thing that I have noticed is if I put print statement next to the playback it prints the whole keyboard input while the game was frozen ,but its unable to play it back anyways.

IDK what to do

My code fragment which takes input and ticks and puts them in the text file.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                increaseGravity = True
                u = " s\n"
                time = str(pygame.time.get_ticks())
                e = time + "," + u 
                f.writelines(str(e))
```

and the code part that is responsible for the playback!

```
if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                f = open("m.txt", "r")
                currtick = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                for x in f:
                    b = x.split(',')
                    cc = int(b[0])

                if cc == currtick:
                    print(" works")
                    keyboard.press_and_release(b[1].strip)
```

and this is how the text file looks, the first are the tick and the second movement made

```
1453, d
1763, d
2752, a
```

Following advice :

```
if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                currtick = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                for x in keyList:
                    # Variable that counts
                    cx = 0
                    # current tick time combined with the movment tick
                    cc = (int(keyList[cx][0])) + currtick
                    
                    # puts key id into xx variable
                    xx= int(keyList[cx][1])
                    
                    #prints both
                    print(keyList[cx][0],keyList[cx][1])
                    #adds +1 to cx
                    cx =+ 1
                # if current tick + time when pressed is equal to current game tick it executes print and presses the key
                if cc == currtick:
                    print(" works")
                    if(xx == 1073741904):
                        keyboard.press_release('a')
```

Comment: you already handle keyboard events for the actual game. all you have to do is add a list or something and push your keys in there as you handle them. if it's a lot of keys you may want to keep on open file handle and write it directly to file

Comment: The problem here is that there is a delay when I try to do it! I have tried writing input and the tick when the input is done to a text file, but when i loop throught it the ticks have a delay and they don't match so the input doesnt work. Do you maybe need to see my code to understand it better?

Comment: some code would help, yes

Comment: no no no, add the code to the question, not as comments

Comment: thanks! new to stack overflow but edited my question

Comment: About using the keyboard librarys record/play function I have a suspicion that it might not work because pygame and record/play function tries to run at the same time, using the input. So that might be the reason why it freezes but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: try an alternative solution of putting everything into a list something like: `key_list.append((pygame.time.get_ticks(), event.key))` and see if that performs better, if it does you can then make an extra thread or async method that will pop things out of the list and write them to the file on its own time, or bite the bullet and write to disk at the end of a game

Comment: Well I tried it but it didnt work, i think it still has a delay? I will put my code that I tried in the post, correct me if you see something wrong but I think it should work. Since im trying to replay moves without closing the programm the ticks continue to count so i have to add the current ticks to the tick when the key was pressed.

Comment: wait, you going over the entire list of key presses every time? that will be the slowest solution! turn your recorded keys to a dictionary with the ticks as keys so you dont have to loop over the list every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example that can record and then replay events with roughly the same time between events.

When the left mouse button is pressed, recording is enabled and `KEYDOWN` events are appended to a list, along with the time they occurred. Left-clicking again disables recording. Right-clicking will start playback of recorded events by [scheduling](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) a custom event to occur. When that event occurs, the recorded event is [inserted into the event queue](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post). Then the timer is set with the time difference between the event that has just been posted and the next event.

```
import time
import random
import pygame

CUSTOM_PLAYBACK_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1


def queue_next_event(event_list, event_index):
    """Set a timer for the next playback event"""
    if event_index == 0:
        timer_duration = 100  # effectively immediate
    else:
        elapsed_time = event_list[event_index][1] - event_list[event_index - 1][1]
        timer_duration = round(elapsed_time * 1000)  # convert to milliseconds
    pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_PLAYBACK_EVENT, timer_duration)
    print(f"{time.time()} Set timer for {timer_duration} ms")


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.Surface([size[0], size[1]])
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color("blueviolet"))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect[0] = pos[0]
        self.rect[1] = pos[1]
        # initially stationary
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        """Move, but stay within window bounds"""
        width, height = screen.get_size()
        if not (self.size[0] // 2) < self.rect.center[0] < (width - self.size[0] // 2):
            self.speedx *= -1  # reverse direction
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if not (self.size[1] // 2) < self.rect.center[1] < (height - self.size[1] // 2):
            self.speedy *= -1  # reverse direction
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Add this draw function so we can draw individual sprites
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        # update speeds based one keypress
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.speedx -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.speedx += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.speedy -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.speedy += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.speedx = 0
                self.speedy = 0
            else:
                pass


# initialise screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.init()
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# create a cube at a random position
cube = Block((80, 80), (random.randint(100, 700), random.randint(100, 700)))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# variables for recording
recording = False
playback = False
playback_index = 0
recorded_events = []

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            else:
                # handle the event
                cube.handle_event(event)
                if recording:
                    # save the event and the time
                    recorded_events.append((event, time.time()))  # event
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:  # Left click
                recording = not recording  # toggle recording
            elif event.button == 3:  # Right click toggles playback
                playback = not playback
                if playback:
                    if recorded_events:
                        playback_index = 0  # always start playback at zero
                        queue_next_event(recorded_events, playback_index)
                    else:
                        playback = False  # can't playback no events
                else:  # disable playback timer
                    pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_PLAYBACK_EVENT, 0)
        elif event.type == CUSTOM_PLAYBACK_EVENT:
            pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_PLAYBACK_EVENT, 0)  # disable playback timer
            # post the next event
            pygame.event.post(recorded_events[playback_index][0])
            playback_index += 1
            if playback_index < len(recorded_events):
                queue_next_event(recorded_events, playback_index)
            else:
                playback = False
    # clear the screen
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    # update sprites
    cube.update()
    # draw sprites
    cube.draw(screen)
    # refresh display
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS

pygame.quit()
```

The recorded events aren't cleared, so if you stop and start recording there'll be a larger gap, there's a debug `print` statement to help keep track of things. Ideally there'd be some visual indication of recording and playback.